# Remote server RDP resolution

Tags: windows, rdp, resolution

I have a remote 2012 R2 base server in the cloud, I am running some scripts that are very dependent on the resolution.

When i connect via RDP and record my mouse actions everything is fine, but as soon as i disconnect the RDP, the resolution changes and everything goes wrong...

It is not possible to keep my computer on 24/7 hence I got that server.

Due to this unstable resolution it's becoming very difficult.

I'm looking for two options:

1. how to keep the RDP alive even after switching off the PC
2. how to get the resolution of the server after disconnecting so that I can record all mouse events in that resolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First of all, instead of using mouse clicks to script, which is going to be fragile whatever you do, I'd suggest investigating ways of scripting things without relying on mouse clicks.**

But if this is *really* what you need to do, then instead of using RDP, if your cloud provider provides remote console access, you would be able to use the system console instead. You can then set up the server to Autologin (https://superuser.com/questions/499724/auto-login-windows-server-2012) to the user running the script on boot. You'd probably want a seperate user for this.

If your cloud provider doesn't allow remote console access, then you might be able to get access to the remote console anyway (at least after the server is booted, which is all you need in this case), using something like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/). (I'd try this process: Set up unattended remote access, reboot the server, and then connect back with Teamviewer. Hopefully you should then be remoted in to the console session of the server.)